# Academic life in China

Tags: tenure-track, academic-life, china

I was offered a tenure track assistant professor position in China. However, I am not familiar with the admin culture and academic environment of China. Is it difficult to cope with the university admin in China? Does the acadmics 'interact' with peers and students differently in China? More importantly, is it going to be a very steep transition in migrating to a Chinese university?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Of possible interest: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104541/20058 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108041/20058 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27553/20058 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/67163/20058

Comment: Look for posts in this forum from the user "Scientist". He is an expert.

Comment: This question seems far too broad to have a useful answer.

Comment: Why not take it as something challenging for personal growth. If you don't like you can always move back to where you are right now. You will be an expert to answer what you are asking, and there is nothing to loose.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a few important questions.  Foremost, I am assuming you know the language -- to what extent do you know Chinese culture?  The transition will be very steep if you do not understand the cultural nuances of all aspects of living and working in China.  Indeed, from a Western standpoint, the interactions between students and faculty are much different.  And, the interactions between faculty and staff are also different.  As you consider the options, I would find out what criteria are used for promotion, and whether you must publish in certain journals on certain lists.  I don't know where you have done your training.  If your training is in a Western university, you may experience a very steep transition if you are unfamiliar with Chinese culture, practices, and norms.