# Postdoc in China age issue

Tags: postdocs, age, china

Ok here's the issue. Normally the Chinese postdocs have to be under 35 years of age plus under 3 years from PhD. However, I am slightly over 3 years from PhD. However, I already will have a one year postdoc experience (currently pursuing) prior to starting a (second) postdoc in China. My age would be around 37 by that time though. So, aren't there any age relaxations for people already having some postdoc experience? By the way, I also have a 2.5 years of University (teaching+research) experience prior to starting my (first) postdoc. This is really an ugly rule if it still doesn't allow any age relaxations provided all the University experience plus a postdoc.

Comment: This is an ugly rule because it does not help you - may help others though...

Comment: @SolarMike What do you mean by that? Do you think disregarding the research experience is reasonable? Do we have to bullfight during the postdoc or do research?

Comment: Perhaps they are trying to prioritise the "younger" field or perhaps they expect the older ones to have moved to relevant positions either in academia or industry...

Comment: Sure that's where I agree with them. Ofcourse the younger the better, however, when someone is continuously in research phase, so I believe in that case there should be some relaxation in age (logically). My question was that whether such relaxation exists or not, in case of second postdocs?

Comment: Perhaps there is provision in your contract for extensions or continuation?

Comment: Actually my current postdoc is not in China, however, I have acceptance by a professor in China for the next postdoc. So it will be a fresh postdoc contract in China.

Comment: So, if you have been accepted, then perhaps they are happy with deviating from "normal"...

Comment: Chinese living in Taiwan here. _I have acceptance by a professor in China for the next postdoc_ Did the professor know your age when he made the offer? If yes, you're fine. If no, tell the professor your age(birth date) now. Sometimes, the rules can be bent, sometimes not. It all depends.

Comment: @scaaahu Actually there isn't an official offer yet, however, he just says "you are welcome to join my group" and he will sort out the details this week, and he just worried about the age issue today, but he said he will check again. So when he said yes the first time, he didn't calculate my age (even though it was explicitly written on my CV) but he found out later perhaps and then I told him that please tell the admin. that this will be my second postdoc, not the first one.

Comment: I was over 35 and beyond 6 years since PhD when I took a postdoc in China. As a foreigner. I was offered another one after that (i.e. +2 age) but I refused. Are you quite sure this age rule is strict? I spent 2 years there and never heard of this. Granted: my Chinese postdoc friends were young, and actually quite few -- postdoctoral fellowships are not popular positions in China. Most prefer a more stable position, even if assistant professor.

Comment: @Scientist Thanks for the info. When was that? I am not 100% sure, but it is normally the case nowadays. However as scaaahu mentioned, there are exceptions so its maybe not that stringent. My prof. is looking into it, and lets see what he says. Whether he can manage workarounds or not.

Comment: My bet is that this is common practice, not a rule. In China there’s a tendency to homogeneity, so whenever somebody attempts anything off the script there’s confusion. I was in south of China 2016-2018 and got another postdoctoral offer at CAS Beijing. No age ever mentioned, so ask again. Off your question: think carefully why you’d like to do a postdoc in China. It’s a mess. I strongly recommend any alternatives.

Comment: @Scientist Many thanks for your helpful information. Don't you think CAS was a good option? What were your main concerns with the postdoc experience you had in China? Was it bad, salary wise or other things like not a good group etc? BTW today I was told that the rule is strict, i.e., no > 35 allowed.. so its already out of question for me now.

Comment: @AtoZ I will not elongate this on comments. I will direct you to my other posts in SE Academia so you understand the issues I faced. Chinese academia felt rotten, with CAS Beijing at the core. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104541/persistent-issues-with-salary-pay-as-a-postdoc-in-china-what-can-i-do?noredirect=1&lq=1 I suggest you answer your own question here with the new rules, to assist someone else. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114805/meeting-dishonest-ex-supervisors-at-large-international-conference-should-one